# Is there a list of linked data from resources mentioned in the annual NAR database issue?

Tags: linked-data, biology

The [Journal Nucleic Acid Research](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/) releases an annual issue on [biological databases](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/41/D1/D1.abstract). Does there exist a subset containing biological resources from the NAR database issue that is exposed as linked data?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are several resources.

[www.bio2rdf.org](http://www.bio2rdf.org) is probably the best known.

To easily browse linked data try
[www.distilbio.com](http://www.distilbio.com)